# Windows 10 port forwarding, (what)command instead GUI?

Tags: windows, port-forwarding

I need to enable port forwarding port 8444 but don't have access to the router, and that's how I've been doing it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLIqu.png)
But every time the internet drops, router will clear this.
Now I'm sure there has to be a command to does exactly the same, does anyone know what command that would be?
I want to set up this command to be sent like every minute so I never again have to check this and type all this manually.
I'm sure someone smarter would write piece of code that checks if this is enabled and then send this command or not but that's not me.

Answer (score 0):

You're configuring the router using the UPnP IGD interface. It's most commonly used by programs to automatically set up port forwarding rules on startup, and so it is **not** unusual that routers forget those rules after reboot and/or after a certain period of time.

Instead, try adding the same rules through the router's webbrowser-based settings page – usually port forwardings added this way *are* permanent.

But if you still want to do this through UPnP IGD, the [MiniUPnP](http://miniupnp.free.fr/files/) project has an `upnpc` command which can query and define port forwarding through the command line.

Comment: As I said I don't have access to the router so I can't set port forwarding permanently, otherwise it would be easy peasy. And yes I'm quite annoyed that the program itself doesn't set it(developers told people to set it in the router directly). UPnP IGD - that's enough for me to carry from there, thanks!